# How to filter numeric strings from list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings

```
lst = ["5g", "100", "devices", "0.5", "degree"]
```

and I want to filter all numbers and get as output

```
["5g", "devices", "degree"]
```

If I use `isnumeric()`

```
[item.isnumeric() for item in last]
```

I get

```
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

`isdigit()` gives

```
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

and `isalpha()` returns

```
[False, False, True, False, True]
```

Is it possible to get desired output using built-in functions?

Comment: It isn't clera what you mean precsiely by "numeric strings" but probably something like `try: float(x): except ValueError: return False; return True`

Comment: you need to write custom function to check a element is float or not. and you can use regex statement to get the result

Comment: `"0.5"` isn't a digit in python land,

Comment: @sahasrara62 using a `try-catch` with `float` is the typical way

Comment: `isdigit` returns false for `.` because, crucially, `.` is not a numerical digit.

Comment: With just built-in functions: `[item.replace('.','',1).isnumeric() for item in lst]` that also catches these add. examples added to your list (".5" True, "7.6." False) `lst = ["5g", "100", "devices", "0.5", "degree", ".5", "7.6."]`